# How do I make Delayed::Jobs (Mongoid) show up in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, delayed-job, rails-admin

I'm trying to get the Delayed::Job model to show up in the rails_admin interface, so that I can view the currently queued jobs from a browser. I've been unable to do this - the model simply won't show up in the interface. I've tried do the following in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` and some variations of that:

```
config.model Delayed::Job do
  label "Delayed Job"
  list do
    field :run_at
  end
end
```

Anyone know how to add the Delayed::Job model to RailsAdmin?

Answer (score 3):

The answer above seemed to add the Delayed::Job model to an empty array (meaning all other models were no longer visible) with the current version of RailsAdmin. What worked best for me in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` was:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.included_models = RailsAdmin::Config.models_pool << 'Delayed::Job'

  config.model Delayed::Job do
    label 'Task'
    navigation_label 'Background Processing'
  end
end
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try include that model in config/initializers/rails_admin.rb (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation):

`ruby
   config.included_models << 'Delayed::Job'`

Comment: This is a great start. Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job is now showing up. Now I'm getting an error when trying to view the list of Jobs though: `undefined method 'page' for #<Array:0x007fe90cad0460>`. I think the problem might be with the route: `http://localhost:3000/admin/delayed~backend~mongoid~job`. Could the `~` be messing it up?

Comment: Seems it's because of Kaminari. Maybe it will help you: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/issues/10